# How can I save money on home insurance?

Tags: home, insurance, cost-cutting, discount, savings

What are some of the easy or not-so-easy ways to save money on home insurance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some ways my family saves money on our home insurance:

- We shopped around, then ended up purchasing our insurance through a group affinity program offered by our university alumni association.
- We combined our home and car insurance with that same insurer.  They gave us a special combination discount.
- We installed a monitored home security system and monitored smoke alarm.  Our insurer has an additional discount for these systems.
- We raised our deductibles.
- From time to time, we look around to make sure we're still getting a good deal.

Here are a couple of good articles on the subject:

- [15 ways to save on homeowners insurance](http://articles.moneycentral.msn.com/Insurance/InsureYourHome/12waysToSaveOnHomeownersInsurance.aspx)
- [How can I save money when I buy home insurance?](http://www.investored.ca/investments/insurance/Pages/how-can-i-save-money-when-i-buy-home-insurance.aspx)
- [Tips to Buying Homeowner Insurance](http://homebuying.about.com/od/hazardfireinsurance/qt/homeinsurance.htm).

Finally - make sure you get adequate coverage!  Make sure you consider your real insurance needs, and not just the cost of the insurance.  If the worst happens, you'll want good coverage with a good company.